# Insert activity history for account using trigger in salesforce?

Tags: php, triggers, salesforce, apex

I have developed small app in salesforce. To pull account records, Process it and push back to salesforce. I want to store activity history for every account when i pushed account records like pushed time and other fields in activity history.

So what shall i do for to store activity history for accounts in salesforce. One of the my friend tell that write a trigger for that, but i dont know how to write trigger for create activity history for each account.
  Every help will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
 Rajendra J.